# Persisting the user after initial login to Backendless

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, backendless

I am trying to make it so that the user can stay logged in even if the app closes. I can't seem to get my function to work correctly. I have a function which logs the user in and it works when the button is pressed, but I can't seem to call the function in the right place to get it to load only after the user has logged in the first time and then closes the app but doesn't log out. Here is my view controller code:

## ViewControler

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


let APP_ID = "i have it"
let SECRET_KEY = "i have it"
let VERSION_NUM = "v1"

var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()




@IBOutlet weak var userEmail: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!


func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}







@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

    let user = BackendlessUser()
    user.email = self.userEmail.text
    user.password = self.password.text


    if userEmail.text == "" || password.text == ""{

        displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter a email adress and password")

    } else{

    backendless.userService.registering(user,
                                        response: { (registeredUser : BackendlessUser!) -> () in
                                            print("User has been registered (ASYNC): \(registeredUser)")
        },
                                        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
                                            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
        } 
    )
    }

}




@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject) {


    if userEmail.text == "" || password.text == ""{

        displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter a email adress and password")

    }else{





 loginUserAsync()


        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

        var initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarControllerID") as! UIViewController
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()



    }
}


func loginUserAsync() {

    let user = BackendlessUser()
    user.email = self.userEmail.text
    user.password = self.password.text

    backendless.userService.login(

        self.userEmail.text, password:self.password.text,

        response: { ( user : BackendlessUser!) -> () in

            self.backendless.userService.setPersistentUser()

            self.backendless.userService.setStayLoggedIn( true )

            self.backendless.userService.getPersistentUser()

            let user = self.backendless.userService.currentUser

            if (user != nil) {

                // get user's email (i.e. mandatory/predefined property)

                let userEmail = user.email
                let password = user.password



                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

                var initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarControllerID") as! UIViewController
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

            else if (user == nil) {

                print("User hasn't been logged")

            }

        },

        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in

            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")

        }

    )

}

func validUserTokenAsync() {
    backendless.userService.isValidUserToken(
        { (var result : AnyObject!) -> () in
            print("isValidUserToken (ASYNC): \(result.boolValue)")
        },
        error: { (var fault : Fault!) -> () in
            print("Server reported an error (ASYNC): \(fault)")
        } 
    ) 
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)



}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loginUserAsync()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}









}
```

Comment: You could store a token or a boolean in user defaults. Then, when the person comes back to the app see if you have that saved value and bypass the login process. Would that work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I'm very new to Backendless. Can you give me a code example?

Comment: My previous solution stopped working all of the sudden :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to call the following function:

```
self.backendless.userService.setStayLoggedIn( true )
```

before "backendless.userService.login", rather than in the login response handler.